# Find the difference in two list that have the same values but are not in the same place

Tags: c#

I want to find in the difference between this two list

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,6,5,7}
```

I try to tred to use `.Excepet`

I want to find where is the difference like the 6 and the 5 are not in the same index in both of the list. And i want to store the index where the number is now.

Comment: Show what code you have tried so far

Comment: Hi @corentin.chrd, can you clarify more on your question on what is the expected result you try to achieve and what is about `.Except`, do you face any issue on it?

Comment: Can you specify what the difference is? Perhaps write what result you would expect from the lists you have given.

Comment: I want to find where is the difference like the 6 and the 5 are not in the same index in both of the list. And i want to store the index where the number is now.

Comment: iterate through all elements of both lists and do something when you found a non matching index

Comment: I will recommend Having all the information in the question not only in the titile. and underline the permutation between the 2 array. At the first reading it look like you where looking for `Except` and had a typo (you wrote `Excepet`).
The most interesting will be to know what result you expect.

Comment: Using some insider information. I will say that you don't need to compare the array as you are the one doing the permutation in your sorting. And that reduction of scope knowing that the array are the same, with only **one** permutation may simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on a limb here, `.Except` didn't work because every item is inside the other list.

Can't you just iterate through list1 and check if the same value is on the same position in the second list?

```cs
var list1 = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
var list2 = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,6,5,7};
var differences = new List<int>();
        
for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    if (list2[i] != list1[i])
    {
        differences.Add(list2[i]);
    }
}
```

And if you want to know the position as well, you can always change the differences list to a dictionary where the key is the index and the value is the actual value.

```cs
var differences = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        
for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    if (list2[i] != list1[i])
    {
        differences.Add(i, list2[i]);
    }
}
```